# Looping through all instances of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

if I have an object constructor like:

```
function cat(color, sex){
     this.color = color;
     this.sex = sex;
}
```

and I make some cats:

```
var fluffball = new cat("blue","male");
var shiznitz = new cat("red","male");
var slothersburger = new cat("green","female");
```

Is it possible to loop through all the cats I have declared? Something like:

```
var current_cat;
for(current_cat in document.cat){
     alert(current_cat.color);
}
```

That doesn't work though. Do people usually store all the cat objects in an array? Or make another object containing an array of the individual cats:

```
function all_cats(){
     this.the_cats = new Array();
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to loop through all the objects you have created unless you kept track of them somewhere (like in the constructor). Something like this-

```
var globalCatArray = [];

function cat(color, sex){
    this.color = color;
    this.sex = sex;
    globalCatArray.push(this);
}

var fluffball = new cat("blue","male");
var shiznitz = new cat("red","male");
var slothersburger = new cat("green","female");

//use globalCatArray to get all instances
```

Watch out though. As long as the objects are in the array, they stay in memory without garbage collected. So if you create a lot of objects, you may want to remove them from the array once you are done with it.

Also, do not use `for..in` to iterate though loops. See this [Javascript Array extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234449/javascript-array-extension/1234482)

Answer (score 7):

You could make a sort of a *CatFactory* object, dedicated to create and track the Cat object instances:

Usage:

```
CatFactory.createCat('fluffball', 'blue','male');
CatFactory.createCat('shiznitz', 'red','male');
CatFactory.createCat('slothersburger', 'green','female');


CatFactory.forEachCat (function () { // forEach abstraction
  alert(this.name + ' is ' + this.color);
});
```

Implementation:

```
function Cat (name, color, sex){
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
  this.sex = sex;
}

CatFactory = {
  createCat: function () {
    var newCat = {};
    Cat.apply(newCat, arguments);
    this.allCats.push(newCat); 
    return newCat;
  },

  allCats: [],

  forEachCat: function (action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.allCats.length; i++){
      action.call(this.allCats[i]);
    }
  } 
};
```

Comment: Absolutely marvellous!  The only piece of code I could find that aglomerates creating the instances AND control/save for future manipulation.  Elegant and genious!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var Cat = (function cat(color, sex) {
    var allCats = [],
        catConstructor = function () {
            allCats.push(this);
            this.color = color;
            this.sex = sex;
        };
    catConstructor.each = function (fn) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allCats.length; i++) {
            fn.call(allCats[i]);
        }
    };
    return catConstructor;
}()); // execute the function immediately
```

With this one, you don't have any nasty global vars, and you don't have to alter your interface from the `Cat` prototype form.

```
var fluffy = new Cat('brown', 'male'),
    kitty = new Cat('black', 'female');
Cat.each(function () {
    alert(this.color);
});
```

You can make your loop interface whatever you want (a `getAllCats()` function which returns an array, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through all of them storing them in array would make sense..

Something along the lines of 
    var cats = [];

```
cats[0] = new cat();

cats[0].color = "red";
cats[0].name = "fluffy";

for ( var cur in cats )
{
    //Do Things
}
```

Sorry for all the edits- half asleep tonight.

Answer (score 0):

since i just had a similar problem, here's one easy solution if you use `jquery`:

```
function Cat(color, sex){
     this.color = color;
     this.sex = sex;
}

var cats = [];
function createCat(color, sex)
{
    cats.push(new Cat(color, sex)));
}

createCat("white", "male");
createCat("black", "female");

//iterating cats by using jQuery's $.each
$.each(cats, function(index, object){
        alert(object.color);
});
```