# JavaScript instances of a class

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function:

```
function Control(value){
    var self=this;
    self.param1=value;
    self.param2=value.text;
}
```

Is it possible to get all instances created by that function in JavaScript?

Comment: The only easy way, that I can think of, is to store a reference to any created `Control` class in some global array. You would do the storing in the `Control` constructor (function above)

Comment: There is no such thing, as I know. You need to have your own mechanism for saving all instances of Control class.

Comment: nope (without tracking them yourself). Otherwise, garbage collectors could not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through all instances of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247956/looping-through-all-instances-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Also note that there are no classes in JavaScript.

Comment: this is my problem. I store them in an array, but then when I clear that array they still appear to exist in memory...

Comment: @razvan How do you know if you don't have a reference to the object? :) In any case, if that's your *actual* problem you might want to ask about *that* specifically to get a solution.

Comment: This happens in a asp.net web application. I am debugging it and I thought maybe there is a way to check if they still exist. The main problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184485/durandal-strange-behaviour).

Comment: to save ram, you can keep a copy of a local function in the array using bind() (instead of the whole object), something like function(){return this}, which when called gives you back the object, if it exists. or, look into WeakMaps if you can like within it's support kingdom.

Comment: If this is for debug purposes then why not use a profiler to take heap snapshots? Like the one in Chrome's Developer Tools > Profiles > Take Heap Snapshot. You won't be able to find the location in code of all the references but you'll know how many of them you have and inspect them.

Answer (score 4):

Without modifying the class, there is little you can do. If you can modify it, simply keep a reference of each instance you construct:

```
function Control(value){
    Control.instances = Control.instances || [];
    Control.instances.push(this);

    var self=this;
    self.param1=value;
    self.param2=value.text;
}

// In case you are worried about garbage collection
Control.prototype.destroy = function() {
    var index = Control.instances.indexOf(this);
    Control.instances.splice(index, 1);
}


// Usage:
var x = new Control();
var y = new Control();
// do stuff with x and y
console.log('There are ' + Control.instances.length + ' instances of Control');
// all done with x and y
x.destroy();
x = null;
y.destroy();
y = null;
// no more references to the two instances, they can be garbage collected
```

Be warned though, you will prevent the garbage collector from freeing the memory of any instance you don't call destroy() on.

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar in one of my projects because i needed to call a method for all the instances...

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    var self = this; // For reference to "this" 
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;


    document.addEventListener( "event/person", function( event ) {
        var params = event.detail.params;
        Person.prototype[ params.method ].call(self);

       // Take params:   params.params => ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
    });
}


Person.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log("Firstname: " + this.firstname + " Lastname: " + this.lastname);  
};


Person.prototype.callAll = function( params ) {
    document.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( "event/person", {
        detail: {
            "params": params   
        }
    }));
};


var a = new Person("Gabriel", "Gatu");
var b = new Person("Marco", "Giovannini");


Person.prototype.callAll({
    method: "toString",
    params: ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
});
```

It uses the listeners to communicate between a simple method and the constructor class, also allows you to call whatever method you want contained in the prototype of the class, passing parameters, if necessary...

p.s. Sorry for the bad english... :)

Comment: `Person.prototype[ params.method ].call(self);` = `self[params.method]()` When your instance goes out of scope the event listener is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in a global array. Would be similar to some static pattern.

```
var controls = [] ; //Global array

function Control(value){
    var self = this;
    self.param1=value;
    self.param2=value.text;

   controls.push(self);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian suggested in his comment you can do it this way:

```
// global are bad though!
var controlInstances = [];

function Control(value){
    // track instances
    controlInstances.push(this)
    this.param1 = value;
    thsi.param2 = value.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar in one of my projects because i needed to call a method for all the instances...

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    var self = this; // For reference to "this" 
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;


    document.addEventListener( "event/person", function( event ) {
        var params = event.detail.params;
        Person.prototype[ params.method ].call(self);

       // Take params:   params.params => ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
    });
}


Person.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log("Firstname: " + this.firstname + " Lastname: " + this.lastname);  
};


Person.prototype.callAll = function( params ) {
    document.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( "event/person", {
        detail: {
            "params": params   
        }
    }));
};


var a = new Person("Gabriel", "Gatu");
var b = new Person("Marco", "Giovannini");


Person.prototype.callAll({
    method: "toString",
    params: ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
});
```

It uses the listeners to communicate between a simple method and the constructor class, also allows you to call whatever method you want contained in the prototype of the class, passing parameters, if necessary...

p.s. Sorry for the bad english... :) See ya !

Comment: If you are worried about the garbage collector i think you have to simply add the destroy method to the class prototype and detach the listener from that object. What do you think about it?

Answer (score -1):

No.

The fact that you can only touch objects that you have explicit references to is [part of JavaScript security model](http://www.slideshare.net/webdirections/douglas-crockford-ajax-security-presentation/43)*.

**That security model is not applicable in JavaScript in cases of global objects.*

Answer (score -3):

```
var foo = new Control('bar');
console.log(foo.param1);
```

Comment: what does this have to do with the question?