# How to I prevent prototypes to show on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'd like to extend the Array functionality with some functions of my own. This is working fine. However, I noticed that in the console the functions are "appended" to the array as if they are data.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BxfCy/1/

And here is the code because stackoverflow is forcing me to post (just click the fiddle):

```
a = [1,2,3];

Array.prototype.doMagic = function(){
    var returnvar = this;
    returnvar.push(42);
    return returnvar;
}

console.log(a);

for (var n in a){
    console.log(a[n]);
}
```

My thought is that other Array functions are not shown in the array (you know, like push). Is there a way to not show the prototyped functions in the array as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Array extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234449/javascript-array-extension)

Comment: For modern browsers, have a look at [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for (var n in a){
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        console.log(a[n]);
    }
}
```

A better way is to [use the right iteration idiom for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description):

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```

Or use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to make the `doMagic` property [not enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'doMagic', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(){
        var returnvar = this;
        returnvar.push(42);
        return returnvar;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using `for..in` to loop, when you should be using a regular `for` loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  console.log(a[i]);
}
```

`for..in` is meant for objects *not* arrays.

**Edit:** In modern browsers you can use `forEach` as well:

```
a.forEach(function(val, i) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: In javascript, an `Array` is also an `Object`.
See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen and yet `for...in` is almost always the wrong way to iterate over arrays.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen: I'm aware of that. What I meant is that `for..in` is used with objects of type `[object Object]` if that makes it clearer...

Comment: @MattBall That is still so true. I did understand what you were saying elclanrs. It's just that there is no 'wrong' way of iterating over an `array`/`object` like that. `for .. in` could do the trick but he would need an `object.hasOwnProperty()` check inside the loop like MattBall was suggesting.

Comment: Arrays are Objects, so `for..in` is meant for Arrays too. It's for enumerating enumerable properties of an object and its `[[Prototype]]` chain in no particular order. It's fine to use it with an Array if iterating enumerable properties is what is required. However, often that isn't what is required since order may not be as expected, hence it's more common to use a plain `for` loop to guarantee the order in which numeric members are accessed.

Comment: @RobG: Right, but it seems clear from OP's question that `for..in` is wrong for this case.

Comment: I read it more that the OP was surprised to see properties on the `[[Prototype]]` were enumerable from an instance. But whatever, they are full–bottle now. :-)